# How to return index of whitespace in a string in python?

Tags: python

I am writing a function for an exercise in CS class.
But I don't know why I am getting this error:
The same code worked without function. I try searching how to find an index of "whitespace" in a string but I could not find any. The purpose of the exercise is to return full name typed by user deleting one random letter from both first name and surname. (This is "assuming" the full name typed by user contains two parts)
Thanks

```
Enter your Full name: Emily Watson
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cs_lec7_char_shuffle_ex.py", line 33, in <module>
    version1 = remove_two_letters(full_name)
  File "cs_lec7_char_shuffle_ex.py", line 16, in remove_two_letters
    gap_pos = full_name.find(" ")                    
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

***Repl Closed***

import random

def get_full_name():

    full_name = input("Enter your Full name: ")

def remove_two_letters(full_name):

    gap_pos = full_name.find(" ")                    
    name_length = len(full_name)                    

    first_name = full_name[0:gap_pos]               
    sur_name = full_name[gap_pos+1:name_length]

    first_random_pos = random.randrange(1,gap_pos)  
    sur_random_pos = random.randrange(gap_pos+1, name_length)

    first_name = first_name.replace(full_name[first_random_pos],"",1)    
    sur_name = sur_name.replace(full_name[sur_random_pos],"",1)         

    removed_name = first_name + " " + sur_name

    return removed_name

full_name = get_full_name()
version1 = remove_two_letters(full_name)

print(version1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined the `full_name` inside the local name space of `get_full_name()`, if you want to use it in another place you need to return it:

```
def get_full_name():

    full_name = input("Enter your Full name: ")
    return  full_name
```

That's what you've got `AttributeError` because your function returns None and you passed None to `remove_two_letters`.

Comment: OH MY GOD Thanks for pointing it out. I have no clue why I forgot to put it in there...  omg lol..  thanks !

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> string_1 = "That's it"
>>> string_1.index(" ")
6
```

Comment: Thank you but I already tried using index(" ") and it generates same error.

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine the error that you are receiving:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

That means that you are trying to access the attribute `find` on an object of type `None`. Let's look at the line producing the error, as indicated in the stacktrace:

```
gap_pos = full_name.find(" ")
```

The find attribute is being called on the `full_name` object. Thus, we can conclude that the `full_name` object is of type `None`.

If we trace the `full_name` variable back through the calling code we see that it was supposedly set by the function `get_full_name()`, which in fact does return `None` due to not having an explicit `return` statement.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Cheers

Answer (score 0):

For the next time, if you want a clue to know what is wrong, you could use type() to find out that this is not the same type between your first full_name and the second full_name, so you just had to return your variable.

I ran the test for you, and I had :

```
def get_full_name():

  full_name = input("Enter your Full name: ")
  print(type(full_name))


full_name = get_full_name()
print(type(full_name))
```

Output :

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'NoneType'>
```